# Frame bundle and $GL_n-$-principal bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am not an expert in algebraic geometry, so my question maybe be trivial for those who are.

All schemes are over $\mathbb C$. Let X be a scheme and $\mathcal E\rightarrow X$ be a vector bundle of rank $n$. I knew from a paper that there is a Frame Bundle $P(\mathcal E)\rightarrow X$ which has a natural $GL_n-$action associated to this vector bundle. And there is an equivalence of categories between the category of vector bundles over $X$ and the category of $GL_n-$principal bundles over $X$.

I searched on Bing and the terms are all about Manifolds, which I think is different from our context.

My question is: is there a good reference for the above construction? Or can anyone show me the detailed constructions? I know little about vector bundles, so any reference for it would also be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, stop using Bing; Google has better results for anything other than...unsavory content. I'm sorry, but I had to say it.

Now regarding your question: what is the paper of which you write? The frame bundle construction on manifolds should translate without any difficulty to smooth varieties and quite possibly to more general schemes, as the statements that you quote suggest. Are there no citations in this paper pertaining to principle bundles on schemes?

Comment: @TabesBridges I know google is far better. But Google is not accessible is China. The paper is ‘Scattering diagrams, Hall algebras and stability conditions’ by Tom Bridgeland. In my mind, schemes are more complicated (e.g. the fiber product is not the Cartesian product and we have to take the structure sheaf into account). The author refers to some paper about stacks but none about vector bundles.

Comment: For example, I would like to know if there is a construction of Hom schemes. Given to bundles $\mathcal E,\mathcal F$ over $X$, is it possible to construct a scheme?

Comment: Yes, it is. For short, I suggest you "Vakil - F.O.A.G." for a very good readable (and enormous) introduction to the subject.

Comment: @Armandoj18eos Thank you for your pretty good reference. Inspired by his exercise 2.2.G and 2.2.11, given a vector bundle $\mathcal E\rightarrow X$, we have a sheaf $\mathcal F$ over $X$ s.t. $\mathcal F(U)=\{f:\mathbb A^n_U\xrightarrow{\sim} \mathcal E|_U\}$. Then we have a topological space $F$. This $F$ should be the frame bundle. Although right now I don’t know its structure sheaf. I think the pullback of $\mathcal F$ along the canonical map from $F$ to $X$ should be a candidate.

Comment: @Goulag Ugh, I'm sorry (re: China and Google), that must be awful. The sheaf $\mathcal F$ is what you are looking for, but if your space $F$ is the space of sections (as described in Vakil 2.2.11), that is not the frame bundle. The space of sections is a strange beast that is, in particular, locally homeomorphic to $X$ (whereas the frame bundle should have rank $n^2$). The contruction you want is generally just called the associated vector bundle of a locally free sheaf, and is described in section 13.1 of Vakil. As for its structure sheaf, you will just want the pullback of $\mathcal O_X$.

Comment: @TabesBridges I am confused now. The ‘sheaf $\mathcal F$’ I described is not locally free: it is not clear that its global section is non-empty. A possible one is the sheaf $\mathcal G$ s.t. $\mathcal G(U)=\{s:U\rightarrow \mathcal E| f\circ s=\mathrm{Id}_U\}$ where $f:\mathcal E\rightarrow X$ is the vector bundle. But it’s rank is also $n$.

Comment: @Goulag Sorry? Locally free sheaves do not need to have non-trivial sections, and indeed anything calling itself the frame bundle shouldn't except in very special cases.

Comment: @TabesBridges At least it should be an $\mathcal O_X-$module. Indeed, some other people call $\mathcal F(U)$ it’s sections.

Comment: @Goulag I don't understand? Of course it has local sections, but not necessarily global sections. And why do you not thing $\mathcal F$ is an $\mathcal O_X$-module?

Comment: @TabesBridges By définition it should be a sheaf of modules. But the empty set is not an Abelian group. Now $\mathcal F(X)$ is usually empty. That’s the reason. If we assume $U=Spec\ A$ s.t. $\mathcal E$ is trivializable, i.e. $\mathcal E|_{U} \sim \mathbb A^n_U$, then $\mathcal F(U)$ is isomorphic to $GL_n(A)$ and I don’t know it’s module structure. Could you please write down some details so that I can check it myself? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think now I figured it out. For a vector bundle $\mathcal E\rightarrow X$ of rank $n$, its frame bundle $P(\mathcal E)\rightarrow X$ is defined as follows:

Let $U_i=\mathrm{Spec}\ A_i$ be an open affine covering of $X$ such that $\mathcal E|_{U_i}$ is trivializable, namely we have $\rho_i: \mathcal E|_{U_i}\xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbb A^n_{U_i}$. Denote by $\mathcal E$ the associated locally free $\mathcal O_X$ module. Consider the sheaf Hom $\mathcal G=\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal O_X^n,\mathcal E)$. Then $\mathcal G(U_i)=M_n(A_i)$. So the associated vector bundle $
\mathcal G$ is defined such that $\mathcal G|_{U_i}=\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathrm{Sym}(M_n(A_i))$. Consider its open sub scheme $D(det(x_{ij}))$ where $x_{ij}$ is a basis of $M_n(A_i)$ as $A_i-$module. This defines an open subscheme of the vector bundle $\mathcal G$ and this is the frame bundle that we want.